# ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: Unknown database 'db/production' when running "eb deploy"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rds

**Dear subscribers.**

I want to create a rails project using amazon RDS mysql db instance.

### WHAT I HAVE DONE.

---

```
1) I created amazon RDS mysql instance at first and assigned the full access authority in security group.<br>
2) I have created a rails new project using sqlite and deployed it to amazon elastic beanstalk using "eb deploy". Worked well.<br>
3) In order to use the amazon RDS mysql, I have changed the config/database.yml as the following.<br>

    production:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
      username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
      password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
      host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
      port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
I have assigned the variables on the tab of configuration in eb instance.<br>
<hr>
```

### Errors when deploying it again using "eb deploy"

---

```
    ERROR: [Instance: i-0c11ecd4] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...options.
    ============= END WARNING FROM mysql2 =========
    rake aborted!
    ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: Unknown database 'db/production'

    Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'db/production'

    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace). 
    Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
    INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
    ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0c11ecd4'. Aborting the operation.
    ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                

    ERROR: Failed to deploy application.

I want to know the quick way to fix.
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the environment variable RDS_DB_NAME set to?

Comment: That is "production"

Comment: How about `ssh to your beanstalk`, `cd to /var/app/current`, then run `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production`?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred when migrating the migrations to RDS.
This was old project which used the sqlite before.
I am not sure I can migrate the migrations to RDS directly.
Please check the errors again.

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'db/production'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace).
```

Because I created the RDS db before, I don't need to migrate it again.
After removing the migrations in db/migrate, the error was fixed.